# Haskell audio output on OS X?

Tags: macos, audio, haskell, core-audio

I'd like to be able to output audio from Haskell. I'm currently using GHC 6.10 on OS X (Snow Leopard). I've tried building the jack library (using JackOSX) and the PortAudio library, but neither of them seemed effective. Is there a relatively simple way to do live audio output from a Haskell program on a Mac?

Edit: Clarity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been using PortAudio successfully.

I took some excerpts from my toy program to make a very simple "echo" example, below:

(run with headphones. this is a feedback loop from the mic to the speakers and may become **very loud** after a few feedback rounds)

```
import Control.Monad (forever)
import Data.Int (Int16)
import Foreign.Ptr (nullPtr)
import Sound.PortAudio

initPortAudio :: Int -> IO (PaStream Int16)
initPortAudio blockSize = do
  Right NoError <- initialize
  Just micDevIdx <- getDefaultInputDevice
  Just spkDevIdx <- getDefaultOutputDevice
  Right paStream <-
    openStream
    (Just (StreamParameters micDevIdx 1 PaInt16 0.1 nullPtr))
    (Just (StreamParameters spkDevIdx 1 PaInt16 0.1 nullPtr))
    44100 blockSize
    :: IO (Either String (PaStream Int16))
  Right NoError <- startStream paStream
  let zeroBlock = replicate blockSize [0]
  Right NoError <- writeStream paStream zeroBlock blockSize
  return paStream

main :: IO ()
main = do
  paStream <- initPortAudio blockSize
  forever $ do
    Right numSampsAvail <- getStreamReadAvailable paStream
    Right curSamps <- readStream paStream 1 numSampsAvail
    Right NoError <- writeStream paStream curSamps numSampsAvail
    return ()
  where
    blockSize = 0x800
```

Works here in Leopard with GHC 6.10.4.

My own toy program actually only uses audio input, and it outputs zeros to audio output (without doing that PortAudio complains).

Comment: How did you install the portaudio library itself? I installed it via macports and now the haskell library is complaining that the portaudio library is the wrong architecture.

Comment: So apparently this is related to Snow Leopard being all 64bit by default, but GHC still being 32 bit. Trying to build portaudio as 32bit also fails.

Comment: @Edward Amsden: I didn't use macports. I did `configure` .. `make install` for the stable version v19_20071207. Good luck.

Comment: Macports failed building the 32 bit library, so I also did configure .. make install. I had to set CFLAGS and LDFLAGS when running configure to force the 32 bit build.

Comment: Might I request that you report this problem to the maintainer for that port?

Comment: I updated the example to work with `portaudio-0.2.4`. source:  https://github.com/sboosali/lts6/blob/109eb47fd579fcc768b0481844db5eabc7589f4f/example/Example/PortAudio.hs readme: https://github.com/sboosali/lts6/blob/109eb47fd579fcc768b0481844db5eabc7589f4f/README.md