# Iterate over list in haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, portaudio

I'm writing an audio program in Haskell using Portaudio. I have a function that generates a list of samples I'd like to play, and I'm trying to play them using the following snippet inside main:

```
curSamps <- return (chunk 1 (sineWave 440 44100))
forever $ do
  Right numSampsAvail <- getStreamWriteAvailable paStream
  Right NoError <- writeStream paStream curSamps numSampsAvail
  curSamps <- return (drop numSampsAvail curSamps)
```

sineWave is a function I've created to generate an infinite list of Int16 samples of a sinewave at a specified frequency and sample rate.

When I debug this code, by replacing the audio output code with a putStrLn, it prints all 0s, which is the first sample from the function.

How can I iterate over this list with the audio output functions? I don't think I can use recursion or a map.

Edit: Code copying mistake

Comment: why do you think you cannot use a map?

Comment: What are the values of the different subexpressions? I.e. what is take 10 (sineWave 440 44100), take 10 (chunk 1 (sineWave 440 44100)), etc.?

Comment: @Edward Amsden: btw, please leave a comment in your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223866/haskell-audio-output-on-os-x describing whether you installed portaudio using macports or not. that may be useful for others, such as me when I switch to snow leopard. thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use recursion:

```
play []       = return ()
play curSamps = do Right numSampsAvail <- getStreamWriteAvailable paStream
                   Right NoError <- writeStream paStream curSamps numSamps
                   play (drop numSampsAvail curSamps)

main = do ...
          play (chunk 1 (sineWave 440 44100))
          ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider using `map`'s monadic cousins [`mapM`/`forM`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad.html).

Comment: Each recursion/loop drops a variable number of samples from the list (`drop numSampsAvail`).  I think that makes it difficult to use mapM.

Comment: @Nefrubyr: We need a monadic fold then.

Answer (score 2):

Using the same API functions one can do this:

```
let playSamples curSamps = do
      Right numSampsAvail <- getStreamWriteAvailable paStream
      Right NoError <- writeStream paStream curSamps numSampsAvail
      playSamples (drop numSampsAvail curSamps)
playSamples (chunk 1 (sineWave 440 44100))
```

I'm not familiar with the Portaudio API, so it might provide a more convenient, higher-level way of doing what you're trying to achieve.